# React Component Gets Unmount When Rendered With the same Key

Tags: reactjs

According to this  [link](https://medium.com/@coolram2104/digging-deeper-inside-the-reconciliation-algorithm-of-react-f0d428ba4ae9) you can avoid unmounting a component by using the same key. In this example iam using the same key but the component gets unmount each time. What am i doing wrong?

```
class Component1 extends React.Component{

  componentDidMount(){console.log('componentDidMount');}
  componentWillUnmount(){console.log('componentWillUnmount');}


  render(){

      console.log('render component1');
      return <div></div>;
  }


}

class App extends Component {

  flag = true;

  action1 = ()=>{
      this.forceUpdate();
  }

  render() {
    console.log('render App');
      if(this.flag){
        this.flag = false;
          return (<div>
            <Component1 key="kaka"/>
            <button onClick = {this.action1}>Click me</button>
          </div>);
      }
      else{
        this.flag = true;
        return (<span>
            <Component1 key="kaka"/>
            <button onClick = {this.action1}>Click me</button>
          </span>);
      }

  }
}
```

Comment: What is forceUpdate() doing ?

Comment: What's your real intent or use case? You have a very trivial example. Please help up understand the overview of the problem or this could lead to an XY problem. The use of `this.flag` instance property is too suspicious, and most of the time you don't want to set it in the render method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `key` doesn't matter because the parent changes inside of your `render` (from `div` to `span` or vice versa).

Per [React's Reconciliation documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html):

> The algorithm will not try to match subtrees of different component types. If you see yourself alternating between two component types with very similar output, you may want to make it the same type. In practice, we haven’t found this to be an issue.

The author of the Medium post appears to suggest otherwise. I don't believe this is correct. Using a `key` suggests stability across changes to a tree, but as noted above, React does not bother reconciling subtrees when the component type changes.

Comment: In the link says: If there is any component which is going to be the same (or consistent) even if the parent node get modified. We can hint the react to preserve the existing instance of component by providing “key” props, so that it can get saved from getting unmounted as shown in snippet below figure

Comment: Modifying the parent node is not the same as replacing it with another type, as far as I am aware.

Comment: Yes but if you see the image, it says that changing the parent node and providing a key to the child, the child doesnt get rendered. The article is faulty?

Comment: @Dolby He appears to have misunderstood the React documentation, yes. I've provided more information and a link to the reconciliation docs.